# Непонятное поведение localStorage

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь сделать кеширование в `localStorage`, но что-то странное с ним происходит.
По идее должен удалять все элементы кроме `cacheBbbbbb` `cacheFfffff`, но не удаляет некоторые. Хотя в списке (если раскомментировать `listStorage();`) выводит все элементы.

Но самое странное, если закомментировать строку `localStorage.removeItem(key);` то список элементов на удаление нормально выводит.

В чем хитрость?

```js
localStorage.setItem("cacheAaaaaa", JSON.stringify({ l:2, t:123}));
localStorage.setItem("cacheBbbbbb", JSON.stringify({ l:3, t:1543001789}));
localStorage.setItem("cacheCccccc", JSON.stringify({ l:4, t:234}));
localStorage.setItem("cacheDddddd", JSON.stringify({ l:5, t:345}));
localStorage.setItem("cacheEeeeee", JSON.stringify({ l:6, t:456}));
localStorage.setItem("cacheFfffff", JSON.stringify({ l:7, t:1543001789}));
localStorage.setItem("cacheGggggg", JSON.stringify({ l:7, t:567}));

maintenanceStorage();
//listStorage();

function maintenanceStorage() {
  for (var n = 0; n < localStorage.length; n++) {
    var key = localStorage.key(n);
    if (key.substring(0, 5) == "cache") {
      if ((Math.trunc(Date.now()/1000) - parseInt(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)).t)) > 172800) {
        console.log("Item removed: " + key);
        localStorage.removeItem(key);
      }
    }
  }
}

function listStorage() {
  for (var n = 0; n < localStorage.length; n++) {
    console.log(localStorage.key(n));
    console.log(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(n)));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что происходит в цикле с `localStorage.length`, когда выполняется `localStorage.removeItem(key);`?

```
  ...
  localStorage.removeItem(key);
  n--;
}
```

Comment: Понял. На такой глупости споткнулся. =)